# Override configureTypeRegistry for Scenario Outline [Cucumber]

Tags: junit, datatable, cucumber

Since cucumber3 [definition of custom data types was implemented](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable#custom-table-types) it works perfectly with Given and another keywords.
But is there any examples how this feature works (if it does) with Examples?

Comment: It works with scenariooutline. scenariooutline is just a repetition of scenarios with different values. Convert ur existing scenario into a single line example table and try it.

Comment: @Grasshopper i've tried, but i couldn't understand, how to pass back (how it should be passed to step) from examples.

For example, I want to transform a row to object (using TableRowTransformer).
So, how it should be passed back to step?

Example:

https://codeshare.io/G7LMrk

Comment: All the columns in the examples need to have a header. A TableRowTransformer is for a datatable and not scenariooutline. I think u may be mixing them up.

Comment: @Grasshopper This confirmed my guesses. Thanks.
There is an additional question: what alternatives can be used for such task? (examples table transformation)
As i see, it works in qaf, but it works with testng and there are a lot of unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Not sure i understand what u mean by 'examples table transformation'? Can u detail what u looking for?

Comment: @Grasshopper
transformation of a table row into a single object, json/xml/txt parsing into examples (the option of using the entire collection as part of a single step is not satisfactory in principle), and so on.
in other words, it's required the use of examples as a data provider for DDT
(example: https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html)